# why the result that returned from the MYSQL to android application is null?

Tags: php, android, json

I trying  to read data in my database  and then use it in my application , for that i am using a php script as a web service to connect to my Mysql db, but my program throw me an exception in the parsing of Json  i tried to remove the parsing section and print the result value on the log and appear that its null  , why the result value is null ? what is the error ?

I have searched over the net and tried all possible solutions but the problem still , please help me ......  what i can do to solve this problem ?

**this is my log when i printed the result value :**

> null
>     after sb.tostring
>      null   in postExecute method

**Exercise.php**

> ```
>    <?php
>      $Name=$_REQUEST['name'];               
>      mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
>     mysql_select_db("MYDB");
>    $sql=mysql_query("select  burnedCalories   from Exercise where  name='$Name' ");
>    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
>    $output=$row;
>     print(json_encode($output));
>      mysql_close();
>      ?>
> ```

**java class**

> ```
>     public class  ExercisesActivity  extends Activity{
> ```

```
            private    String    selected_ex_Name ="Walking";
            private int  calorie_factor;
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.exercise_details);
                new ConnectTask().execute();


                 }

    private class  ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
     {    
 private  String result="";
 private  InputStream is=null;
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


 try
 {
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",selected_ex_Name));
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/Exercise.php");
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  is = entity.getContent();
         }
    catch(Exception e)
      {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

          }
        catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
         }

        Log.e("log_tag", result+ "after sb.tostring  ");
        return result;
        }


 protected  void onPostExecute(String  result){

               Log.e("log_tag", result+" in postExecute method ");

            //           try{
     //                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   //                   JSONObject json_data=null;
  //                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
  //                    {
  //                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  //                                calorie_factor=json_data.getInt("burnedCalories");
           //                   }
            //  
            //               }
            //                  catch(JSONException e){
             //                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data  "+e.toString());
              //                    }

          }

                }}
```

Comment: Did you check that php script in the browser? Does it print output? Because for me the http://10.0.2.2/Exercise.php doesn't work. If you can't connect with a browser, you can't do it with the app, that is why it gets null

Comment: I used 10.0.2.2 to run the app on the emulator , and the php script work on the browser

Comment: I don't think it is a problem but you have `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));` twice. Try to `Log` the `is` variable. Is it null too?

Comment: no it isnt null >> E/log_tag(479): org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@45022e30     this its value   what this mean ? please help me .

Comment: It means that it connected to the script. So the output must be an empty String. Maybe there is something wrong with the "name" variable which you send to the script? Try manually setting the name in php and querying it with an app. As an aside - sanitize your database queries, this one is vulnerable to SQL Injtection attacks.

Comment: thanks , but can you explain more  , how i can do that ? ,because iam new in android and php .

Answer (score 0):

Your php script is on http://10.0.2.2/Exercise.php, so probably on some local machine. Even if you can access it from your browser and it shows JSON output, your app can't reach it. So put it on external server and connect to it from there - you'll have to change the url in `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/Exercise.php");` to the new one.

When you do this it'll be possible to check if you really have some reachable JSON output, because from what your Logs look, it seems that you don't have one.